# EF Core 7 - Ignore virtual properties in model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm updating an ASP.NET Web API on .NET 4.6 to .NET 7 and I have some issues with EF Core. I'm using a HTTP `POST` to create a new event and I'm getting this error:

> Status: 400
> One or more validation errors occurred
> The Trs field is required
> The Reason field is required
> The LineStatus field is required

These are all virtual properties on `Event`:

```
public partial class Event
{
    public int IssueId { get; set; }
    public int? IssueNum { get; set; }
    public int? IssueNumH { get; set; }
    public int IssueVersion { get; set; }
    public bool Replaced { get; set; }

    public int TrsId { get; set; }
    public int ReasonId { get; set; }
    public string? Comments { get; set; }
    public int LineStatusId { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeEnd { get; set; }

    public int EventEditorId { get; set; }
    public int? Ticketuid { get; set; }

    public DateTime? TimeEndValue { get; set; }

    public int Archived { get; set; }
    public int? OriginalEvent { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int? RelatedEvent { get; set; }

    public virtual LineStatus LineStatus { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ReasonTree Reason { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual WorkOrder? Ticketu { get; set; }
    public virtual TrsId Trs { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I've tried to use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on these properties but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I've also commented them out because I don't need the relational objects yet. This makes it to the controller method and I can see that the event has all of the properties it needs to match in the database table but when it calls `SaveChanges`, I get this error:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'ReasonTreeId'.
> Invalid column name 'TrsId1'.
> Invalid column name 'WorkOrderTicketuid'.

I'm not really all that familiar with EF Core, is there some way to set up my models in the model builder to tell it to ignore properties when model binding? Is there something else that I'm doing wrong?

Here is the endpoint on my controller and the model builder:

```
    // POST: api/Events        
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Event>> PostEvent(Event @event)
    {
        if (_context.Events == null)
        {
            return Problem("Entity set 'TrsContext.Events'  is null.");
        }
        _context.Events.Add(@event);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetEvent", new { id = @event.IssueId }, @event);
    }
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.IssueId);

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.IssueNum, "IX_Events_IssueNum");

    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Replaced, e.TrsId, e.TimeStart, e.TimeEnd }, "IX_Events_Replaced_TrsID_Start_End");

    entity.Property(e => e.IssueId).HasColumnName("IssueID");
    entity.Property(e => e.Archived).HasComputedColumnSql("(case when [TimeEnd]<dateadd(year,(-1),getdate()) then (1) else (0) end)", false);
    entity.Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
        .HasColumnType("datetime");
    entity.Property(e => e.EventEditorId).HasColumnName("EventEditorID");
    entity.Property(e => e.IssueNum).HasComputedColumnSql("(coalesce([IssueNum_h],[IssueID]))", false);
    entity.Property(e => e.IssueNumH).HasColumnName("IssueNum_h");
    entity.Property(e => e.LineStatusId)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))")
        .HasColumnName("LineStatusID");
    entity.Property(e => e.ReasonId).HasColumnName("ReasonID");
    entity.Property(e => e.Ticketuid).HasColumnName("ticketuid");
    entity.Property(e => e.TimeEnd).HasColumnType("datetime");
    entity.Property(e => e.TimeEndValue)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("(coalesce([TimeEnd],getdate()))", false)
        .HasColumnType("datetime");
    entity.Property(e => e.TimeStart).HasColumnType("datetime");
    entity.Property(e => e.TrsId).HasColumnName("TrsID");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.LineStatus).WithMany(p => p.Events)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.LineStatusId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Events_LineStatus");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Reason).WithMany(p => p.Events)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.ReasonId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Events_ReasonTrees");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Ticketu).WithMany(p => p.Events)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.Ticketuid)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Events_WorkOrders");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Trs).WithMany(p => p.Events)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.TrsId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Events_TrsIDs");
});
```

Comment: In short - do not use the entities as API models, create special classes for that (`CreateEventModel`, `CreateEventDto`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding is not a part of EF Core, it is a part of the ASP.NET Core. Arguably the easiest option would be to just create a simple `DTO`/`Model` class for the scenario and remove extra fields in it and then map it to the entity (optionally using some mapping library like `AutoMapper`):

```
public partial class CreateEventModel
{
    public int IssueId { get; set; }

    public int? IssueNum { get; set; }

    // List only needed fields here

    public int? OriginalEvent { get; set; }

    public int? RelatedEvent { get; set; }
}
```

Optionally you can move shared fields to some base class.

Notes:

- [Preventing mass assignment or over posting in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/preventing-mass-assignment-or-over-posting-in-asp-net-core/)
- > I'm updating an ASP.NET Web API on .NET 4.6 to .NET 7

  Recently .NET 8 was released which is [new LTS](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). .NET supports end on May 14, 2024 so probably you should consider moving to .NET 8.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I have a different project that exposes entities on the api but it only has one table so it works fine... but now I'm wondering if I should always use view models/dtos. I'm guessing this is best practice? Part of the appeal of EF to me was how fast it was to develop but adding another layer to a small project feels like overkill.

Comment: @Tom if you will use AutoMapper then development speed would not be that affected IMO.Personally I always separate entity models and Domain/Model/DTO classes. But for smaller project you can do it only in places where it is needed. Alternatively you can 1) disable nullable reference types 2) try making reference props nullable and explicitly make them required (via EF Core fluent API)

Comment: @Tom also consider moving to .NET 8. See added note